# A 3x3 grid of numbers with unique row and column medians

Tags: mathematics, combinatorics

Can you place every number from 1 to 9 into a 3x3 grid such that the median of every row and column is a unique value? The median of a row is the number that is greater than one number and smaller than another number in that row (similarly for columns).

**Bonus question:** Can you find 4 different solutions, such that 2, 3, 4, or 5 are **not used** as medians?

Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The medians have values ranging from 2 to 8, so exactly one of these values does not appear as the median of one of the 6 rows/columns.

Here are three templates that allow you to choose any missing median value.

> ```
>  1 a 5  a
>  8 4 6  6
>  9 7 b  7
>
>  8 4 5
> ```
>
> where {a,b}={2,3}
>
> ```
>  1 2 a  2
>  3 8 b  b
>  c 9 7  7
>
>  3 8 a
> ```
>
> where {a,b,c}={4,5,6} with a>b
>
> ```
>  1 3 b  3
>  2 6 4  4
>  9 a 5  a
>
>  2 6 5
> ```
>
> where {a,b}={7,8}

For completeness, here are the solutions this produces:

> ```
>  No 2         No 3
>
>  1 3 5  3     1 2 5  2
>  8 4 6  6     8 4 6  6
>  9 7 2  7     9 7 3  7
>
>  8 4 5        8 4 5
>
>
>  No 4         No 5         No 6
>
>  1 2 6  2     1 2 6  2     1 2 5  2
>  3 8 5  5     3 8 4  4     3 8 4  4
>  4 9 7  7     5 9 7  7     6 9 7  7
>
>  3 8 6        3 8 6        3 8 5
>
>
>  No 7         No 8
>
>  1 3 7  3     1 3 8  3
>  2 6 4  4     2 6 4  4
>  9 8 5  8     9 7 5  7
>
>  2 6 5        2 6 5
> ```

Comment: Love your work as always! By the way No 6 can be obtained from No 4 by doing 9-x.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky Indeed, but you mean 10-x. That is actually how I got the 7/8 template from the 2/3 template, though I then reordered the rows to sort the first column, putting the 1 in the top left corner.

Comment: Ah yes sorry it's 10-x

Answer (score 4):

Here is one solution:

> 1 2 9
>  3 5 8
>  7 4 6

Answer (score 2):

No 2:

> ```
>  2 8 9 - 8
>  3 5 7 - 5
>  4 6 1 - 4
>  | | |
>  3 6 7
> ```

No 3:

> ```
>  3 1 2 - 2
>  6 5 8 - 6
>  4 7 9 - 7
>  | | |
>  4 5 8
> ```

No 4:

> ```
>  1 8 9 - 8
>  4 5 6 - 5
>  2 7 3 - 3
>  | | |
>  2 7 6
> ```

No 5:

> ```
>  5 2 1 - 2
>  8 7 3 - 7
>  9 4 6 - 6
>  | | |
>  8 4 3
> ```

Comment: Sorry but 3 is used as a median twice.

Comment: @DmitryKamenetsky; fixed